# incrementing a pointer instead of incrementing an array an it's index

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, increment, pointer-arithmetic

so I have the following problem

```
if(buffer[i]== ' '&&buffer[i+1]==' '&&buffer[i+2]==' ')
    { 


        buffer[i]= '*';

        putchar(buffer[i]);

        i = i + 2

        continue;  
    }

    putchar(buffer[i]); 

    i++;
}
```

this part of the code replaces 3 blanks with a *.

so my challenge is to replace all the array access into pointer-arithmetic

```
char *tmp0_pointer; // initialised in  main function


 if(*tmp0_pointer== ' '&&*tmp0_pointer+1==' ' &&*tmp0_pointer+2==' ' )

{ 
   tmp0_pointer = buffer+i; 

      *tmp0_pointer= '*';
    i = i + 2

    continue;  
}
tmp0_pointer = buffer+i;
putchar(*tmp0_pointer); 

i++;
}
```

However the code below doesn't provide the same result. 
I have a feeling I am not incrementing the pointers correctly.
Could someone help me out ?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You are not incrementing the pointers correctly and you are also not dereferencing them correctly. The first step is to format them.

Comment: Note that `a[i]` is equivalent to `*(a + i)`, and that the parentheses are necessary.  And the array notation is by far easier to get right, witness the struggles you're having doing it the other way.  The compiler doesn't care — make life easy on yourself and use subscript notation for subscripting operations.  If you use `*ptr` only (equivalent to `ptr[0]`), then the dereferencing notation can be sensible.  As soon as you're working with `*(ptr+1)` etc, you're using the wrong (meaning 'not the most sensible') notation.

Comment: In your rewrite, stop using `i`; your pointer increases, and you don't need `i` too.  Or, at least, if you keep both, use `i` to limit how much work is done, but increment the pointer not using `i`.

Comment: given what you want to do this '*tmp0_pointer+1== ' ''  should be '*(tmp0_pointer+1)== ' ''

Comment: Is it really the intention to modify the buffer so that `abc   def` becomes `abc*  def`?  It might be the intended behaviour, but it's a little odd.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler yeah it's my intention I have to do it like that so that it becomes easier for me to translate it to assembler language

Comment: I use compilers to convert C into assembler — and then into object code.  It's a better use of my time.  You might care to note that the original outputs a `*` when it detects 3 blanks and the rewrite doesn't.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler yeah I know thats the problem I am trying to solve

Comment: In both your last two comments to me, the "it" or "that" to which you refer isn't clear. There's an art to writing comments — you should include enough context that your comment is clear taken in isolation. (For example: "I know that's the problem I am trying to solve" might be referring to the absence of a `*` in the output in the rewrite, or (somehow) "better use of time" or "using compilers to convert C to assembler" — or something else. If it's the missing `*`, using assembler won't help. If you've time to waste, you're lucky. If you consider using compilers a problem, then I can't help.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thanks for your help I have found my mistake next time I will be clearer when writing comments

Comment: @T.Obadiah thank you '*tmp0_pointer+1== ' '' should be '*(tmp0_pointer+1)== ' ' thats what I had wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given an array `int arr[5] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };`

And you have a pointer `ptr` that points to the start of the array, generally `ptr + i` points to `i` places ahead in the array which will be equivalent to `arr[i];`.

So in your case using pointer arithmetic `*(ptr + 2) === arr[2]` and so on, the parenthesis are required.

You could continue incrementing the pointer `ptr++` or whatever, but you have to make sure not to go beyond your array memory space.